# React Vis LineMarkSeries style property, separate stroke and fill for Line and Mark

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-vis

I have this in my component:

```
<XYPlot height={300} width={500} xType="ordinal" yType="ordinal">
  <XAxis />
  <YAxis />
  <LineMarkSeries
    data={data1}
    style={{line: {fill:"red"}, mark: {fill:"red", stroke: "black"}}}
  />
</XYPlot>
```

so i am trying to have `line` and `mark` as color red, but border of `mark` as black.

But this is not working!
I am trying out According to [documentation](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/series-reference/line-mark-series) , this doesn't seems to work.

When i tried `inspect element` for a `mark` in browser and change css in `stroke` from red to black, the black border for mark works.

However, instead of `style` property, `color="red"` or `stroke="red"` works, but i am unable to achieve what i am trying. 
(line and mark as red and mark border black)

What am i missing out, Please help me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just found out from this documentation [here](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/master/docs/line-mark-series.md#style-optional) on github which is updated.

`lineStyle={{stroke:"red"}}
 markStyle={{stroke:"black", fill: "red"}}`

This works !
the documentation on official site [here](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/series-reference/line-mark-series) needs to be updated.